# Result of 'Zstack<Content>' initializer is unused

Tags: swiftui, initialization, multiplatform, vstack, zstack

I'm a beginner (started a week ago) in SwiftUI and trying out different things with app development. I'm stuck with Zstack not being able to execute anything.
This is multiplatform app, and when I simulate it, it's just blank white space.
When I erase zstack, and just run with vstack, it does the same thing.

[image: What's the problem here?]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have created an app that is not based on SwiftUI but based on UIKit.

When creating your app make sure that you choose the following options:

- Interface: SwiftUI
- Life Cycle: SwiftUI App

[image]

Then looking in the Project Navigator you should see something like this:

[image]

You should then put your SwiftUI code inside the `ContentView.swift`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                LinearGradient(
                    gradient: Gradient(colors: [.green, .white, .blue]),
                    startPoint: .topLeading,
                    endPoint: .bottomTrailing
                )
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Which would give you something like this:

[image]

If you are a beginner with SwiftUI then I suggest that you look at some tutorials, [hackingwithswift.com](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui) is a good place to start.